# Python, error (error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat) installing a module (docx)

Tags: python, module, pip, docx

I am currently trying to install the docx module for python 3.4.0 using

```
pip install python-docx
```

The install works fine until it reaches   building `lxml.etree` extension   where it then gives the line   error: Unable to find `vcvarsall.bat`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are several duplicate questions. Do you have https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266 ("Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 ") installed?